# How can I add a non singleton on to a DotNet Core 3.0 Worker Service?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I have written a Windows Service using the new Worker Service in dotNetCore 3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration

I am now trying to add some services. One in particular for logging using Sentry.

Deep down in the Add it has a Transient service (the SentryClient)

```
.ConfigureLogging(loggerFactory =>
    loggerFactory.AddSentry(configuration["logging:sentry:dsn"]));
```

When I try and run it I get this Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'SharpRaven.IRavenClient' while attempting to activate
>   'MyServiceName'.

How can I add services which are not singleton?

I have read about this before but I now can't find the article. Do I have to create a factory

EDIT:
Here is the Create Host Builder

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    // The worker class
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

                    var cronExpression = configuration[ActiveDirectoryJobConstants.CronExpression];

                    // Add Quartz services
                    services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
                    services.AddSingleton<QuartzHostedService>();

                    // Add our job
                    services.AddSingleton<SyncWithActiveDirectoryJob>();
                    services.AddSingleton(new JobScheduleDto(typeof(SyncWithActiveDirectoryJob), cronExpression));

                    services.AddSingleton<ILdapConnector, LdapConnector>();
                    services.AddUserServiceClient(configuration);
                    services.AddSentryClient(
                        configuration["logging:sentry:dsn"],
                        hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName);

                })
        .ConfigureLogging(loggerFactory =>
                loggerFactory.AddSentry(configuration["logging:sentry:dsn"]));
```

Comment: All services to be injected need to be registered with the service collection

Comment: @Nkosi I have done that I think

Comment: I see no implementation of `IRavenClient` being added.

Comment: Essentially thats what the AddSentryClient was doing. in the end added what was in that extension and changed the " services.AddScoped<IRavenClient>" to "services.AddSingleton<IRavenClient>". 
Thanks for your help. I have managed to get it working its just not very glamorous.